# Изменение значения регистра: ошибка или особенность

Tags: c, ассемблер, gcc

Есть такой код на C:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void a()
{
    asm volatile("int $0x10": :"b"(0x0700));
}

void b(uint8_t color)
{
    asm volatile("int $0x10" : :"b"(color));
}

int main(){
    a();
    b(7);
    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции с помощью gcc 5.3 с опциями `-S -O2 -march=i686 -m32` внутри функции `main` получается такой ассемблерный код:

```
pushl   %ebx
movl    $1792, %ebx /*1792=0x0700*/ 
int $0x10
movb    $7, %bl
int $0x10
xorl    %eax, %eax
popl    %ebx
ret
```

Видно, что перед вторым прерыванием в регистре `%ebx` содержится вовсе не 7, а 0x0707, то есть регистр `%bh` не обнуляется. Это ошибка компилятора или какая-то особенность встроенного ассемблера? Если последнее, то где это описывается в документации? Ещё я заметил, что если указать другой тип переменной: `asm volatile("int $0x10" : :"b"((uint16_t)color));`, то всё компилируется, как и нужно.

Comment: Рискну предположить что виною всему явное указание типа (uint8_t) для параметра color. По умолчанию компилер может считать регистр 32-битным (и это видно при первом mov в ebx). А 8-битное значение он пишет в bl и получается вот так. Второй фактор - явное отсутствие пролога и эпилога в функциях, из-за чего значения регистров не восстанавливаются.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов тут же функции встраиваются, да и ещё и флаг оптимизации присутствует -- зачем пролог и эпилог?

Comment: Были бы они - не было бы этой проблемы, регистры бы восстановились наверняка.

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете компилятор языка C и при этом делаете ассемблерные вставки. Компилятор ни как не может догадаться, чего именно вы хотите получить. Он же не знает, что выполняет `int 0x10` и какие регистры ему нужны на входе. Если вы делаете ассемблерую вставку, то корректность ее выполнения полностью на вас. А значит вы должны передавать параметр того типа с которым работает ваше прерывание, а ни как не меньше. Компилятор никогда не догадается что надо загружать 8 битное значение в 16 битный регистр из за того, что после вы вызываете прерывание которому BX нужен целиком. Вот и приводите сами тип к int16, как собственно и делаете.

По поводу документации, [вот например](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), первое, что нашел google. Читаем:

> The input operands need not be lvalues. The compiler cannot check whether the operands have data types that are reasonable for the instruction being executed. It does not parse the assembler instruction template and does not know what it means or even whether it is valid assembler input.

Так и сказано, компилятор не проверяет типы данных операндов. Не разбирает ассемблерные инструкции и не знает, что они означают и даже, что это корректный ввод. P.S. Кто английский хорошо знает, подскажите как оно точно должно звучать.

Comment: Просто более логичным, наверное, будет такое поведение, когда для каждой вставки используется четырёхбайтный регистр полностью. Например, если использовать не переменную, а число 7, так и будет. С другой стороны, если привести тип к uint16, то все равно будет использоваться `%ebx`, а не `%bx`. Вот про это и интересно было бы почитать в документации.

Comment: @Imieee imho вполне логичное поведение. старшую часть bx вы можете адресовать отдельно, как bh, поэтому, что бы ничего точно не испортить он int8 грузит в bl. А старшая часть ebx отдельно не доступна, следовательно портить там в общем то нечего, вы когда захотите ее поменять все равно весь регистр загрузите (да, видимо сдвигом принебрегаем), а 32bit операции выполняются быстрее